# Scroll Bar in Openlayers 3 popup

Tags: javascript, html, popup, openlayers-3

In this example of OPenlayers 3  : http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/ ,
I was trying to make the ol3 popup scrollable whenever the content in it is very large. I set the following style for popup content div :- `<div id="popup-content" style="max-height:300px;overflow:auto;">`
This inserts scroll bar if content is greater than 300 px but disables mouse events like zoom,hover,click etc.
Could anyone tell why is this happening and what is the right way to add scroll in popup?

Comment: You could use this tiny plugin - https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-popup

Comment: @JonatasWalker Thanks! I used it. but i am facing a weird issue in my application that when i click on a marker, map does not autopan and the popup is displaced vertically downwards as shown in the snapshot at this link- http://imgur.com/acO9Ewt
Could you please tell me what might be the possible reason behind this?

Comment: Please create a fiddle to demonstrate it.

Comment: @JonatasWalker I already created and tested a separate code for this and it works fine.The problem is in my application.I just wanted to know from you if you could provide me a slight idea as to why this type of problem might have arisen. No issues, I will solve it myself. Thanks..:)