# How to add scroll bar to popup in openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, css, openlayers-3

I'm trying to add the scroll bar to popup with large size using openlayers-3. Anybody help? :-)

I tried..

```
.popover-content {
    padding: 9px 14px;
    height: 197px;
}
```

or

```
div.popup {
    width: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

but it was bad....

Comment: can you add your HTML code as well?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: [Scroll Bar in Openlayers 3 popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238752/scroll-bar-in-openlayers-3-popup). Could not flag it because there is no answer accepted. One there suggested to use this tiny plugin - github.com/walkermatt/ol3-popup. Hope this could solve your problem!

Comment: Thanks for help :-)